# Loopback mixins not working?

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm trying to use mixins in Loopback, but it seems I'm making some stupid mistake.

I defined the following mixin in "common/mixins/test.js"

```
module.exports = function(Model, message) {

    console.log(message);

};
```

In the "user.json"  file I put the following:

```
{
  "name": "user",
  ... , 

  "mixins":{
      "test":"hello world"
  }
}
```

I did not change the meta property in the "model-config.json" file , it is

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  ... ,
  "user": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": true,
    "options": {
      "emailVerificationRequired": true
    }
  },
...
}
```

I expect to see "Hello world" when I start the server, but nothing is logged, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mixin options should be an object.

Try this please :

```
"mixins":{
      "Test":{"message": "hello world"}
  }



module.exports = function(Model, options) {

    console.log(options.message);

};
```

Comment: @WardBeullens I updated my answer. The mixin name should be `Test` not `test`

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! It works. I tried capital letters and an options object before coming to stackexchange for help, but apparently I did not try both at the same time.

Comment: @WardBeullens You're welcome. Yes, it's should be pascal case

Comment: It is a pity that there are no error messages for this though, it would have saved me a few hours.

Comment: @WardBeullens Actually it throws an exception when the mixin not found

Comment: Mmh wierd, I didn't get any error message at all and everything worked except the mixins.